# How to validated Assertion for SAML 2.0 Bearer at SalesForce.com

Tags: salesforce, assertion

I have generated Assertion for SalesForce.com.

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm

I am trying to use SAML Bearer flow but I am getting invalid assertion message when I exchange Assertion.

Is there any way to validate SAML bearer assertion @ salesForce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - currently, the SAML Assertion validator in the Salesforce console only works with SSO assertions.

Comment: how should i test valid SAML assertion ?